# Is inverting slope map same as inverting surface in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, slope

Is inverting a slope map the same as inverting a surface?

I found code on this website https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000006694

The code is following:

```
(([elevgrd] - Z_Max) * -1) + Z_Min
```

Can I use slope map instead of elevgrd ,maximum slope value instead Z_Max and minimum slope value instead Z_Min?

I want to do something like least cost path analysis in ArcGIS but my main goal is to find the hardest path between two points.

Comment: Did you try with raster calculator?

Comment: Yes, I used raster calculator. I wrote there (([slope_map] - 40) * -1) + 1. 40 was the highest value of slope and 1 was minimum value

Comment: To invert the scaling on any value (Vin), you can use the following: 

1. Vrange = Vmax - Vmin,   2.

Vout = (1 - (Vin - Vmin) / Vrange) * Vrange + Vmin

Answer (score 2):

**Technically No** you can't use Slope

**Instead**

You should use (Elevation Raster) instead of (Slope raster)

**Why**

Because (Elevation Raster) represents the surface but (Slope Raster) is representing the most frequently run on an elevation dataset.

So the (Slope) is just a characteristic of the elevation which it can be computed using

```
slope_degrees = ATAN ( √ ([dz/dx]2 + [dz/dy]2) ) * 57.29578
```

According to ESRI, [Raster Surface tools](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/an-overview-of-the-raster-surface-toolset.htm) in ArcGIS considers that Slope is one of the surface tools.

**--How the inverting surface works:--**

In general, it's mathematical approach to be done.

**ArcGIS Code:**

```
(([elevgrd] - Z_Max) * -1) + Z_Min
```

Where: [elevgrd] is the name of the input surface, Z_Max is the surface maximum and Z_Min is the surface minimum.

**In your case (Wrong):**

Because you used the slope values not the elevation values

```
[elevgrd]  = [slope_map]

Z_Max = The maximum slope from your raster = 40
Z_Min = The minumum slope from your raster = 1
```

**Example** 
As you can see from both pictures how the max and min values are different (Elevation VS Slope)

[image]

[image]

Comment: My main problem is that I want to do something like least cost path analysis in ArcGIS but my main goal is to find the hardest path between two points. I followed course here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0Eywj4pIu8

Comment: My main problem is that I want to do something like least cost path analysis in ArcGIS but my main goal is to find the hardest path between two points. I followed course here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0Eywj4pIu8                                     I tried to do it with original surface grid and also with inverting surface grid (computed by equation:(([elevgrd] - Z_Max) * -1) + Z_Min) but results were in both cases same and not correct. Then I tried to invert slope map with the same equation (([slope_map] - the highest value of slope) * -1) + min value of slope ) and result was better

Answer (score 2):

Per your comment, if you want to have steeper slopes to have lower cost for a least cost analysis, just subtract the slope in degrees from 90. So near vertical slopes will have a cost of near zero and flatter areas will have a cost nearer to 90.  Eg

```
90 - [slope degrees]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform the values of a cost dataset, you can indeed use the linear transform that is used in the example. In fact, this equation comes from a more generic equation of linear transform: linearly changing the range of a dataset (from oldmin to oldmax) into a new range (from new_value_of_min to new_new_value_of_max) with inversion:

```
newvalue = (old_max - pixel_value)*(new_value_of_max - new_value_of_min)/(old_max-old_min)+new_value_of_min
```

if you have slopes in degrees, the maximum (theoretical) value of your slope is 90°, so this gives

```
newvalue = (90 - pixel_value)*(90-0)/(90-0) + 0 = 90-pixel_value
```

if you want to invert slope percentage in a new range based on your data, then you have new_value_of_min=old_min and new_value_of_max=old_max, which yields

```
newvalue = (old_max-pixel_value)*(old_max-old_min)/(old_max-old_min)+old_min = (old_max-pixel_value)+old_min (equivalent to (pixel_value-old_max)*-1+old_min )
```

Remark : If you don't invert, then the generic equation is

```
newvalue = (pixel_value-old_min)*(new_value_of_max - new_value_of_min)/(old_max-old_min)+new_value_of_min
```

disclaimer: while your suggestion is mathematically correct, you should make sure that it makes sense in your case (without the context, is is difficult to say.

1. The impact of the slope is not always linear, so a linear transform is not always the best choice for a cost. Also, before assessing the weight of different costs, it is usefull to fix the same range for all (same new max and new min for all cost dataset)
2. a slope raster only gives you the maximum slope at the pixel. So it is ok for the cost of, e.g., building a house, but if you want to consider a displacement then you should measure the slope in the direction of movement (using cost path in spatial analyst, for example). And in the case of a displacement, you should most of the time avoid the "zero" cost.

Small tip: in raster calculator, if the statistics have been computed, you can directly use "your_raster".minimum and "your_raster".maximum